# Parameter remote_user in role include is deprecated, what's the workaround?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

I'm using Ansible to do the automation of my systems.

I have an Ansible playbook that depends on two roles.
The first role creates a user ("specific_user") on a remote server.
The second role uses this user to do a bunch of stuff.

My first solution was the following (my playbook) :

```
---
- hosts: all

roles:
  - { role: ansible-role1, remote_user: root }
  - { role: ansible-role2, remote_user: specific_user }
...
```

However, I'm getting the following warning from Ansible when running it:

```
Using 'remote_user' as a role param has been deprecated.
In the future, these values should be entered in the `vars:` section for
roles, but for now we'll store it as both a param and an attribute..
```

What is the alternative ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this is only a warning message (until version 2.7 of Ansible).

As the message suggests, you need to change syntax to (using YAML in the example below, because it's more readable):

```
roles:
  - role: ansible-role1
    vars:
      remote_user: root
  - role: ansible-role2
    vars:
      remote_user: specific_user
```

...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understood the warning now it's clear

Comment: I'm getting the following warning now : `Found variable using reserved name remote_user` and have some followups questions :
1) is your suggested syntax equivalent to { remote_user: root } ?
2) can you override role vars using this syntax ?

Comment: This is clearly in transition phase in Ansible. What version do you use? Were you using a different version when you asked the question?

Comment: I'm still using the same version : 2.3.0, and for Python 2.7.5. I'm gonna try to update ansible.